# scrollTo doesn't work when it is behind a view with alpha

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, android-espresso

I can't make `scrollTo` to work when the `EditText` is behind a `LinearLayout` with alpha background.

I wanted to avoid uiautomator cause I think it doesn't work sometimes

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
<ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
   <EditText />
   <EditText />
   <EditText />
   <EditText />
   ....
   <EditText android:id="@+id/name" />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/white80">

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
onView(withId(R.id.name)).perform(scrollTo(), typeText(name), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

It says that it can't find the id name. It works fine if the screen is big but if it's small and the edittext name is behind the button_group which has an alpha backgroound, it always fail.

Comment: Could you post the error you get? Does it says something about visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could alter the `button_group` visibility with a custom `ViewAction` before performing the scroll.

Firstly, you need the custom ViewAction that performs the change in the visibility:

```
private static ViewAction setViewVisibitity(final boolean value) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Show / Hide View";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            view.setVisibility(value ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    };
}
```

And then:

```
onView(withId(R.id.button_group)).perform(setViewVisibitity(false));

onView(withId(R.id.name)).perform(scrollTo(), typeText(name), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

And later on you can restore the `button_group` visibility whenever you want:

```
onView(withId(R.id.button_group)).perform(setViewVisibitity(true));
```

Give it a try. As the `button_group` will have its visibility set to `GONE` it should not interfere with the scroll.